# Is there a built-in method to convert pandas dataframe to list of pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas

I am converting a dataframe to a list of series. Currently I am doing it with:

```
df_list = [df[x] for x in list_of_columns]
```

This line is working fine for me, but is there a built-in method of DataFrame to do this?

Comment: Not that I know of, but this seems like a perfectly reasonable way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
df_list = df.as_matrix()
```

returns numpy array